# better loop structure for counting in python

Tags: python, for-loop, counting

The following code tries to count how many external edges some sub-graph structure has. `substructure` is a list of nodes, `graph[node]` returns a list of nodes which are the neighbors of `node`.

```
external_edge = 0
for node in substructure:
    for neighbor in graph[node]:
        if neighbor not in substructure:
            external_edge += 1
```

Is there a better way to achieve this? I tried list comprehension but `external_edge+=1` is not an expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need only the number of external edges

```
len(node for node in substructure for neighbor in graph[node] if neighbor not in substructure)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well.. it is not more efficient but maybe a little more pythonic (using list comprehension with sum function).

```
external_age = sum(1 for node in substructure for neighbor in graph[node] if neighbor not in substructure)
```

Comment: IMO two `for` statements in a single list comprehension should be avoided. Try to use `itertools.product` if you can.